# Publishing Excel as Webpage

Tags: excel, vbscript, html, publish

I am trying to save excel as a webpage using VB Script. The problem I am facing is the sheet names in excel (E.g. Sheet1) also gets saved in webpage. I don't want the sheet name to be present in webpage.

One solution that I found was that if the excel is published as webpage (instead of saving as webpage) then it will not contain the sheet names. But I am facing issues while I try it using VB Script. Below is the code:

```
Dim objApp, objBook, objRange, objSheet
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objApp.Visible = False
Set objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Dashboard\excel_files\Account Executive.xlsx")
Set objSheet = objBook.worksheets("Account Executive")
Set objRange = objSheet.Range("C5:I30")

With objBook.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, "C:\EXCEL_TO_HTML_RANGE.htm", "Account Executive", objRange.Address, xlHtmlStatic, "Title of the page").Publish(True) 
End With


objBook.Close
objApp.Quit
Set objSheet = Nothing
Set objRange = Nothing
Set objApp = Nothing
```

This code gives a unknown run time error with code 800A03EC. 
Is there anyway to correct this code or some other way to remove the sheet names from the web page?

Thanks in advance. :)

Thanks to @AxelRichter
The final working code with excel 2010:

```
Dim objApp, objBook, objRange, objSheet

Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objApp.Visible = False

Set objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Dashboard\excel_files\OU Dashboard.xlsx")
Set objSheet = objBook.worksheets("OU Dashboard")
Set objRange = objSheet.Range("C5:J30")

Dim oPOs, oPO
Set oPOs = objBook.PublishObjects
Set oPO = oPOs.Add(4, "C:\Dashboard\EXCEL_TO_HTML_RANGE.htm", "OU Dashboard", "$C$5:$J$30", 0, "TableDIVID", "Title of the page")
oPO.Publish (True)

set oPO = Nothing
set oPOs = Nothing
Set objSheet = Nothing
Set objRange = Nothing


objBook.Close False
set objBook = Nothing 
objApp.Quit
Set objApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems with your code.

First: The constants `xlSourceRange` and `xlHtmlStatic` are probably undefined. So use their values instead. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823068.aspx for XlSourceType and XlHTMLType.

Second: The `With` needs the object returned by the `Add` and not the response of `Publish`.

Third: You have messed the `DivID` with the `Title`.

```
Dim objApp, objBook, objRange, objSheet
Set objApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objApp.Visible = False
Set objBook = objApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Dashboard\excel_files\Account Executive.xlsx")
Set objSheet = objBook.worksheets("Account Executive")
Set objRange = objSheet.Range("C5:I30")

With objBook.PublishObjects.Add(4, "C:\EXCEL_TO_HTML_RANGE.htm", "Account Executive", objRange.Address, 0, "TableDIVID", "Title of the page")
 .Publish(True) 
End With


objBook.Close False
objApp.Quit
Set objSheet = Nothing
Set objRange = Nothing
Set objApp = Nothing
```

The `With .. End With` can be replaced with the following code for debugging:

```
...
Dim oPOs, oPO
Set oPOs = objBook.PublishObjects
Set oPO = oPOs.Add(4, "C:\EXCEL_TO_HTML_RANGE.htm", "Account Executive", "$C$5:$I$30", 0, "TableDIVID", "Title of the page")
oPO.Publish (True)
...
```

Comment: I tried with the edited code. Now I am getting the following error in the With statement :
This method or property is no lomger supported in this version of Excel.

I am using Excel 2010. Is there any other solution for the problem?

Comment: Cannot reproduce because I have not Excel 2010. It works for me with Excel 2007 as `test.vbs`. Please try the following: Open new Excel Workbook. Put the code in a `Sub` within a `Module`. Now step through the code with `F8`. Which error where?

Comment: I tried what you suggested. Its giving the same error in WITH statement.

Run time error: 1004
This method or property is no longer supported in this version of Excel.

Comment: It is unclear which method is meant. So try replacing the `With .. End With` with the code I have supplemented in my answer.

Comment: there are two scenerios:
case 1: with the above edited code, its giving application defined or object defined error in oPO.Publish (True)


case 2 : I edited add statement with this: 
Set oPO = oPOs.Add(SourceType = xlSourceRange, Filename = "C:\Dashboard\EXCEL_TO_HTML_RANGE.htm", Sheet = "Account Executive", Source = "$C$5:$K$30", HtmlType = xlHtmlStatic, DivID = "Book1_4170")

following is the error in add statement:
Run time error: 1004 This method or property is no longer supported in this version of Excel.

Comment: To case 1: I had my drive P: within the answer. Please try with your C:. To case 2: It must be `Set oPO = oPOs.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, Filename:="C:\EXCEL_TO_HTML_RANGE.htm", Sheet:="Account Executive", Source:="$C$5:$K$30", HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic, DivID:="Book1_4170")`. Note the `:=` in properties assigning. But don't use this syntax in `VBS` because the constants are probably undefined there.

Comment: to case 1 : I tried with C:\ itself. The error was what I stated above.
To case 2: I used just = and not :=. Sorry that was copy paste error. For the constants, xlSourceRange and xlHtmlStatic are the names to constants, so we can use them directly without assigning them.
I found on this link [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839450.aspx)

Comment: To case1: Sure you have write access to `C:\ ` ? Maybe try `Set oPO = oPOs.Add(4, "C:\Dashboard\EXCEL_TO_HTML_RANGE.htm", "Account Executive", "$C$5:$I$30", 0, "TableDIVID", "Title of the page")`? If this not work then I'm not able to support you. Maybe someone other with Excel 2010 will do.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. The code is finally working. But there is a small problem. The excel file is not getting closed and as a result the vbscript also keeps running. I am attaching the final code as a edit to above question. Hope you can help as I am very new to VB Script.  Thanks :)

Comment: Consider `objBook.Close False` as I have used in my code. Note the `False` which says "do not save changes". This is important since you have added a `PublishObject` which not shall be saved in the file.